# How to create a new page in jasper ireport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have to display the detail of a group in each pages.
So it should be 1 group for 1 page and the another group should be display in another page as well.
 I am using *iReport* version 4.6.0. I cannot find the "Create on a new page" property.

Please tell me how to Group and Create on a new page in this version.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the size from each page at menu "Format-> Page format...". Then create Detail Bands as many page you need. Each Detail Band need to have the same dimensions of the page as you set before in Format menu. You need to put each group in one Detail band separately and iReport set automatically each detail band in one page.